# SharePoint List items with the same titles using ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

What i need is to add  a script to Visual Web Part  witch would display ListItems with same titles in textbox by clicking button. 
As a foundation i used this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(MainFunction, "sp.js");

var objContext = null;
var objWeb = null    
var objList = null;
var objItem = null;

    function MainFunction() {  
        objContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        objWeb = objContext.get_web();  
        objList = objWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("Product");

        objContext.load(objList);

        objContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail));  
    }  

    function onSuccess(sender, args) {
        alert('Item Count: ' + objList.get_itemCount());
    }  

    function onFail(sender, args) {  
        alert('Some error has occured.');  
    } 
 </script>
```

My question is: "Is there a way to somehow improve this script to accomplish my goal?"

Comment: Does it work already? What do you want to improve? This better fits at [CodeReview.SE] or [sharepoint.SE] (flagged for moving)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPList list = web.Lists["CustomList"];
            SPQuery qry = new SPQuery();

            qry.Query = @" <Where><Eq> <FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>" + TextTitle.Text + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

            SPListItemCollection result = list.GetItems(qry);

            TextBoxCheck.Text = result.Count.ToString() + " matches has been found";
```